# Contact Form 7 is not redirecting the "Thank-You" page with the removal of CSS and JS of plugins

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

I was working on on-site speed optimization. I removed the css and js files of the Contact Form 7 plugin. Through the following code in function.php

```
function rjs_lwp_contactform_css_js() {
        global $post;
        if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'contact-form-7') ) {
            wp_enqueue_script('contact-form-7');
             wp_enqueue_style('contact-form-7');
    
        }else{
            wp_dequeue_script( 'contact-form-7' );
            wp_dequeue_style( 'contact-form-7' );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rjs_lwp_contactform_css_js');
```

As a result, I can't access the Thank you page. Mail goes correctly, but is not redirected to the "thank you page". Showing Error after root domain: abc.com/#wpcf7-f139-o1 etc. How it is possible if I removed both files and the page also redirect.

I set Redirect Code in the Form

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = '/thank-you/';
}, false );
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to this Stack. Third party plugin questions (like about Contact Form 7) are off topic here, sorry. You can ask via their official support forums instead.

Comment: Well how is Contact Form 7 supposed to trigger `wpcf7mailsent` if you removed its scripts? You're dequeuing them if the form shortcode isn't inside the post content, but if the form is in a widget or template then the scripts are not going to be loaded.